# Seaborn histogram makes columns white

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

In what cases Seaborn makes histogram columns white? I use it Seaborn in Jupyter notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
```

Then I plot histogram using this function:

```
def plot_hist(data, xlabel, bins=None):

  if not bins:
      bins = int(np.sqrt(len(data)))

  _= plt.xlabel(xlabel)
  _= plt.hist(data, bins=bins)
```

As a result in some cases I have histograms with all blue columns or some blue and some white or only white columns. Please, see attached pictures.

How to make Seaborn always draw blue columns?

[image: blue columns]

[image: blue and white]

[image: white]

Comment: Normally white would appear in a theme with a black background. Maybe some functions you call change the theme?  Try explicitly setting the palette to the [default palette](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html), just before calling `hist`with `sns.set(palette='deep')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the `edgecolor` for the histogram is `white`, and as you increase the number of bins or decrease the width of the bars the `edgecolor` begins to cover the `facecolor`. You should be able to fix it by using a higher dpi,

```py
# globally
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
# or for only this figure
fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
```

a thinner `linewidth`,

```py
# globally
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['patch.linewidth'] = 0.5
# or for only this plot
_= plt.hist(data, bins=bins, linewidth=0.5)
```

or remove the outline altogether,

```py
_= plt.hist(data, bins=bins, edgecolor='none')
```

Note that the global methods may need to be after `sns.set()` as this may override them.

Comment: Thanks! A thinner 'linewidth' makes things better only to some extent. Bars are still very pale, almost white in some cases. Higher dpi does not help, it just increases image size. Removing outline has no effect at all.

Comment: @dokondr Did you try a line width of 0.0?

Comment: Interesting, that standard matplotlib.pyplot plots everything correctly with default settings.

Comment: @dokondr matplotlib no longer defaults to outlines for histograms, but seaborn adds outlines to the style in `sns.set()`

Comment: @dokondr The docs were misleading about `edgecolor`, it should be 'none' not `None`. `plt.hist(data, bins=bins, edgecolor='none')` will work as well (and I’ve edited the answer accordingly)